Are there elements in the 2024 Borderlands movie from games beyond the first two?
The 2024 Borderlands movie seems to be very loosely based on the first Borderlands game (2009), while incorporating weapons, characters, and locations from Borderlands 2 (2012). As someone who has primarily played the series up to Borderlands 2 (with some time spent on The Pre-Sequel and Tales from the Borderlands), I'm curious about the film's connections to the games that came after the first two.
Does the movie include any elements (such as weapons, objects, characters, locations, or other references) that were introduced in games after Borderlands 2? Specifically, I'm referring to Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel, Tales from the Borderlands, Borderlands 3, Tiny Tina's Wonderlands, or New Tales from the Borderlands. Are there any Easter eggs or references that only players of these later games would recognize?
